# apt-get update hanging forever after 'Reading package lists...' and not completing

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, virtualbox, vagrant

I have a VM guest running Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS on a Windows 10 host. I access it via Vagrant.

Recently, I updated VirtualBox on Windows, and didn't realize that my Guest Additions was behind on the Ubuntu guest. I'm trying to update things, but when I run `apt-get update`after doing `vagrant ssh` to connect to the box, it looks like it is working and then just hangs at the `Reading package lists...` stage forever (as in I've never seen it complete even after running it overnight).

Here's the full text of it:

```
$ v ssh
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-36-generic i686)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

  System information as of Wed Nov 15 05:41:36 UTC 2017

  System load:  0.22               Processes:           93
  Usage of /:   11.7% of 39.34GB   Users logged in:     0
  Memory usage: 3%                 IP address for eth0: 10.0.2.15
  Swap usage:   0%

  Graph this data and manage this system at:
    https://landscape.canonical.com/

  Get cloud support with Ubuntu Advantage Cloud Guest:
    http://www.ubuntu.com/business/services/cloud

339 packages can be updated.
238 updates are security updates.

New release '16.04.3 LTS' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.


sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package virtualbox-guest-dkms
sudo apt-get update
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security InRelease [65.9 kB]
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease
Ign http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ InRelease
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates InRelease [65.9 kB]
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Sources [146 kB]
Hit http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Release.gpg
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release.gpg
Hit http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Release
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Sources [66.4 kB]
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg
Hit http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Packages
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main i386 Packages [632 kB]
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Sources [407 kB]
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en
Get:7 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe i386 Packages [193 kB]
Ign http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Translation-en_US
Ign http://toolbelt.heroku.com ./ Translation-en
Get:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Sources [195 kB]
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/main Translation-en [370 kB]
Get:10 http://security.ubuntu.com trusty-security/universe Translation-en [111 kB]
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main i386 Packages [977 kB]
Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe i386 Packages [432 kB]
Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/main Translation-en [511 kB]
Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates/universe Translation-en [234 kB]
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en
Hit http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US
Fetched 4,405 kB in 10s (402 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
```

I have no idea why it won't finish or how to tell if it is even making progress.  My goal is to update Virtualbox Guest Additions. What should my next steps be?